# Django2 is trying to render Jinja2 templates, even though it's a REST API

Tags: django-rest-framework, jinja2, datadog, django-2.2, django-rest-viewsets

We're utilizing the `django-rest-framework` to create a RESTful API and using generic views or view sets to create the endpoint views. There is no templating happening, all the frontend is in React.

However, upon watching the traces in Datadog, we're seeing that SOMETIMES (not every time), Jinja2 is rendering, causing a 500-800ms latency. Does anyone have any clues to why this might be happening and how to turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was / is an issue with `rpy2`, which was a dependency of our project. It was being imported by a utility module that was imported on startup. This caused it to be called on every single request to our REST API endpoints. Putting the import inside the actual function that was using it fixed this issue.